# Css overwrite list styles

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css

I have in my rails app `reset.css` with

`ul, ol, li {
    list-style: none;
}`

but i don't want to have it on some pages,i want to keep it default(default css styles)

How can i set default values for it?

my div with list

```
 <div class="text_blog">
    <ol>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
    </ol>
   </div>
```

it can be `ol`or `ul` list

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the _default css_  on other pages but on _this specific page_ you want to set other css values?

Comment: i want to use default css styles for this(page/div).but others should use `reset.css`

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want to reset style? I think you want to target specific HTML elements instead!

What I mean is instead of targeting ALL lists (ul, ol), only target those you want to remove the list-style on!

In your code that is the ones inside the class `.text_blog`.

Your HTML should look like this:

```
 <div class="text_blog">
  <ol>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ol>
 </div>

 <div>
   <ol>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
   </ol>
 </div>
```

And your CSS:

```
.text_blog ol {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Note that the first div has the class `.text_blog` and therefore the CSS only targets that specific div.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r1xefz1q/

---

Edit: If you want to target the list elements, not the div move the class attribute to the list element instead. Apply the class attribute to all lists that you want to override the style on!

That way it works on the different lists!

If that means you have to go through all your lists updating their class, I would take that job in order to keep your code readable and understandable! :)

HTML:

```
 <div class="text_blog">
  <ol class="customListStyle">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ol>

  <ul class="customListStyle">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ol>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ol>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.customListStyle {
    list-style: none;
}
```

New fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r1xefz1q/1/

Comment: Are you sure you want to reset style? - i don't :)But its large app,so i should fix only small part of it.

Comment: Therefore you should use a class, and att the class attribute to the lists you want to change style on. If you do not want to target the DIV, but rather ONLY the lists: Add the class attribute to the list element, not the div element! Check out edited answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried everyting but all I seem to be figuring out is that if you remove the `ul, li` from the origional and place a `.text-blog ol` on `initial` it *sort of*  works. goodluck!

```css
.text_blog ol {
    list-style: initial;
}
ol {
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
 <div class="text_blog">
  <ol>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ol>
 </div>

 <div class="second">
   <ol>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
   </ol>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with [list-style](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp) css property to set default styles.

```css
.text_blog ol {
    list-style-type: numeric;
}
```

```html
<div class="text_blog">
    <ol>
       <li>1</li>
       <li>2</li>
       <li>3</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```